# How to find elements inside Shadow DOM from Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, shadow-dom

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

executable_path = "D:\python\Новая папка\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('D:\python\Новая папка\JJICBEFPEMNPHINCCGIKPDAAGJEBBNHG_3_2_0_0.crx')

def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="D:\python\Новая папка\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
    )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url='https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sawed-Off%20%7C%20Apocalypto%20(Factory%20New)')
time.sleep(10)
root1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME('csfloat-item-row-wrapper'))
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
print(shadow_root1)
```

I tried to get a float from #shadow-root but i cant
[steam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdx3F.png)

How i can to get the information of float in python selenium

I tried to use pyshadow and other modules